# keyboard input to movieClip actionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two alternatives to move a space ship movieclip.

First one is adding eventListener(keybordEvent) check which button is pressed and act according to it.

The second one is again,adding an eventListener(keyboardEvent) and using 4 boolean varaibles,leftArrow,rightArrow,upArrow and downArrow. keep track of pushed buttons and use eventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME) and move movieClip in everyframe using these bool variables)

Which one is better or at least does any of them have an advantages ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the second option because you want to handle movement in the game loop and not in the key event.

Comment: what do you mean by key event ? @Nambew

Comment: The keyboard events want the key is down or up. 

Most games engines handle the key action in the game loop (EnterFrame or Timer) because you want a smooth movement and you probably need to handle collision.

Comment: yeap After I changed it to second version, now it is more smooth however not perfect, is there other tricks to improve it ?

Comment: You can check your fps at runtime to see fps drop. You can use Adobe Scout, Monster Debugger or code library to view this information. Adobe Scout is a good tool for profiling code, you only need to create a Adobe account and you can download for free.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Boolean method as the other method (depending how you implement it) could react to the key repeat that happens when you press a key down - it triggers once, pauses, then continues to fire.

**EDIT**

..and, I agree, also for the best practices reason Nambew mentions!

Comment: one more question, my movieclip moves correctly but,it seems it is not continuous, I dont know how to explain my problem but ,It does not move smoothly but moves like step by step.Could I explain my problem  and If I could, do you know how could I solve it ?

Comment: it sounds like you were using the first method which would react to the key repeat. Use the second method and have the movement controlled every frame or in a timer

Comment: Okey, I'll change it .